# How it is working gc_maxlifetime

Tags: php

Have this session settings:

```
@ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
@ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 1);
@ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60);
  session_set_save_handler('_sess_open', '_sess_close', '_sess_read', '_sess_write', '_sess_destroy', '_sess_gc');
 function _sess_gc($maxlifetime) {
      echo "GC started";
  }
```

As far as I understand with this settings a garbage collector should run every 60 seconds (because probability and divisor are the same). Im testing this now and strange thing is that GC runs everytime im refreshing the website, it is not waiting until 60 seconds has passed from previous call. It is a bit confusing for me, do I understand something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

session.gc_probability / session.gc_divisor = x

In your case x = 1. (= 100% chance)

This means that the garbage collector will run on EVERY request. That is every request anybody makes.

The garbage collector will ONLY delete sessionfiles that are stale and eligible for deletion, NOT files that were recently modified.
What is considered stale is defined by session.gc_maxlifetime

Comment: ok. But what sessionfiles exactly will be deleted? I have my sessions data stored in DB. and I have my own cleaning function like: function _sess_gc($maxlifetime) {
          DB::exec("delete from table_sessionswhere expiry < " . time() ); }.  So if this function runs every page request this gc_maxlifetime has no meaning for me

Comment: If you are using your own session storage (like in a database), the garbage collection as you posted is useless. Build your own. Simply add to your database a timestamp and update it whenever you update a session. Then add some code that sometimes cleans up the table, looking for old sessions. YOU must implement this yourself. So: Just add some code in your _sess_gc function that deletes old records.

Comment: yes, but not all gc functions are useless. Im using gc_divisor and gc_probability to set how to run the _sess_gc function. Only the expiry date I set myself, not based on the gc_maxlifetime .  Or I can do it the way you suggested, i.e. check session timestamp when saving it.

Answer (score 1):

GC does not always run on every request, default PHP settings is that it is 1% chance to run GC. `session.gc_probability` (default 1) / `session.gc_divisor` (default 100) = 0.01 (1% chance)

Relevant manual entry: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability

My suggestion is to store last time a session was touched and check against that value on every page load and if enough time has passed, `session_destroy` and redirect user to login page.

I think you should also try adding this in inside of your _sess_open after where you started your session. After `session_start()` line add

`session_write_close(); // dump $_SESSION out to file, close file, release lock.`

See if any of these will remedy your situation also.